# List of Classes implementing an Interface

Tags: java, list, class, interface

Is there a way to implement something like

```
    List<Class<? implements MyInterface>> ClassList = new ArrayList<Class<? implements MyInterface>>();
```

my goal is to create a hashmap from that list, where the keys are the toString methods of the class (defined in MyInterface) and the values are the classes itself. The toString method of every object of this class returns the same result. This way I could create Instances of the classes using the map by searching the right strings.

thank you for trying to help,
greetings

Comment: Looks like a convoluted way to reach your final goal. Perhaps you can just have a list of enums. These enums can give the name of class you want, and you can create an instance by reflection. Keep the toString() method to display useful information, eg. for debugging purpose.

Comment: Let me get your goal...You have an interface `MyInterface` having method `toString`. Now `ClassA implements MyInterface` & suppose toString() of Class returns "ClassA". So from your hashmap, you will search for value of key "ClassA", which should be class type of ClassA. And than you want to create an instance of returned class type (ClassA in our case)...Is something like this...?

Comment: yes hemu, thats was my goal but I am currently searching for information about the method PhiLho suggested. How would you do it if you'd want to achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
List<Class<? implements MyInterface>> ClassList = new ArrayList<Class<? implements MyInterface>>();
```

should be

```
List<Class<? extends MyInterface>> ClassList = new ArrayList<Class<? extends MyInterface>>();
```

there is **no implements keyword** in the world of generics. if you want a type parameter that implements an interface , use the **extends keyword** to represent it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem interested by the way I explained, here is a quick implementation, to verify it can be done...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

enum NumberClass
{
  ONE("One"),
  TWO("Two"),
  THREE("Three");

  private final String className;

  NumberClass(String name)
  {
    className = name;
  }

  String getName()
  {
    return className;
  }
}

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<NumberClass> numbers = new ArrayList<NumberClass>();

    numbers.add(NumberClass.ONE);
    numbers.add(NumberClass.THREE);
    numbers.add(NumberClass.TWO);
    numbers.add(NumberClass.ONE);
    numbers.add(NumberClass.THREE);
    numbers.add(NumberClass.ONE);
    numbers.add(NumberClass.TWO);

    SomeNumber[] nbs = new SomeNumber[numbers.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (NumberClass nbC : numbers)
    {
      SomeNumber nb;
      try
      {
         nb = (SomeNumber) Class.forName(nbC.getName()).newInstance ();
         nbs[i++] = nb;
      }
      // Cleanly handle them!
      catch (InstantiationException e) { System.out.println(e); }
      catch (IllegalAccessException e) { System.out.println(e); }
      catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }
    for (SomeNumber sn : nbs)
    {
      System.out.println(sn.getClass().getName() + " " + sn.getValue());
    }
  }
}

// The following must be in their own files, of course
public interface SomeNumber
{
  int getValue();
}

public class One implements SomeNumber
{
  public int getValue() { return 1; }
}
public class Two implements SomeNumber
{
  public int getValue() { return 2; }
}
public class Three implements SomeNumber
{
  public int getValue() { return 3; }
}
```

If it doesn't answer your question, consider it as educational material, I hope. :-)

Comment: thank you very much for helping PhiLho and taking the time writing a nice example code, which is very useful. My implementation currently still uses the method I described above but I will definitly change it when I am finished with my current task. Your solutions seems alot more professional, greets and ty again