# Having a list of a certain class that implements an interface

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class, `Component`, and an interface, `IInventoriable`.  I need to have a list of objects that are *only* of class Component, and implement the IInventoriable interface, similar to [this answer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13838523/2584408).

Example psuedocode -

```
public List<Component implements IInventoriable> Inventory;
```

How might I accomplish something like this / is it even possible in C#?

Would a better solution be to subclass `Component`?  For some context, I'm using an entity-component system found in many game engines like Unity.

Comment: You could try linq `OfType` when populating the list. list can be List<Component> but when populating it or filtering the list you can use linq extension `Inventory.OfType<IInventoriable>()` which will only return the Component derived objects that also implement `IInventoriable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try linq `OfType` when populating the list. list can be `List<Component>` but when populating it or filtering the list you can use linq extension `Inventory.OfType<IInventoriable>()` which will only return the `Component` derived objects that also implement `IInventoriable`

Or

create your own List derived generic class with those constraints

```
public class InventoriableComponentList<T> : System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
    where T : Component, IInventoriable {

    public InventoriableComponentList()
        : base {

    }

    public InventoriableComponentList(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(collection) {

    }
}
```

Comment: List derived class with constraints is the answer.

Comment: @Nkosi Apologies for the newbie question, but how would I declare an object of this type?  `public InventoryList<Component, IInventoriable>` would be my best guess, but that doesn't work.

Comment: you would first have to have a class that inherits from `Component, IInventoriable`. like `public class ExampleClass : Component, IInventoriable { }` and then you can declare it like `public InventoryList<ExampleClass> {get; set;}` if it was being declared as a property

Comment: Do you have any classes that match the type constraints?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible without type params. With type params you can do something like

```
int Method<T>(List<T> inventory) where T : Component, IInventoriable { ... }
```

you could give your class a type param with that constraint, which will then always be `Component implements IInventoriable`, but then you'd have to figure out how to set it, which probably wouldn't be possible without another type param, then another ...

---

However there are some other options:

- Separate the `IInventoriable` functionality from the component. For instance, make `Component` objects have an instance variable `inventoryItem`, which is an `IInventoriable`. If the component's aren't inventoriable, than their `inventoryItem` will be `null`. Then make a list of these `inventoryItem`s instead of a list of components
- Make `Component` into an interface, and have the `IInventoriable` interface `implement` it
- If you're not going to use the `Component` functionality, just have a `List<IInventoriable>`
- If you absolutely know that all `IInventoriable` objects have to be `Components`, do a runtime check; have a `List<IInventoriable>` and cast to a component when needed